# Replacing a special character with a \n but keeping the text in the same 'column'

Tags: c#

I have a c# app that reads a text file and looks for ^ characters and replaces them with \t.  It also looks for | characters and attempts to replace them with \n.  This .txt file should then be copied into a spreadsheet.  The problem is that when the app replaces | it creates a new row of cells.  I want it kept in the same cell.

For example the input is:

```
This^is^testing^to^see|if|it|works
```

The output I need is:

```
This    is    testing    to    see 
                               if
                               it
                               works
```

Instead I get:

```
This    is    testing    to    see 
if
it
works
```

I am currently using:

```
 File.WriteAllText(textBox1.Text, File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text).Replace("|", "\n"));
 File.WriteAllText(textBox1.Text, File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text).Replace("^", "\t"));
```

Where am I slipping up?

The closure of this question was of no help.  \r\n does the same thing.  I need the replacement of the | delimiter to keep the information in the same cell.  As you can see it the above example it is moving it a row down into the A (first) column thanks to the \n I assume.

Comment: What output format are you creating? csv can escape newlines, if you quote fields correctly. Tab delimited text wont work.

Comment: You need to use proper CSV-aware code to write these values, so that the newlines you want to keep in a single field of a single row do in fact stay there. The way you're doing it now, the newlines denote a whole new row of data (as you can see). See duplicate for how to write CSV properly.

Comment: You are missing four tabs.  The output you want is putting data in the 5th column.  What you are getting is data in column one.